# Can google web toolkit(GWT ) used on AIX?

Tags: gwt, aix

1. Is AIX support GWT app.
2. If no then do we have any other app like GWT which can run on AIX?

Answer (score 1):

The programs generated by GWT are web applications (GWT makes it possible to develop the frontend, i.e. the user interface for a web application, in Java), so you can use a GWT app anywhere.

The developer tools for creating a GWT app are Eclipse, an Eclipse plugin, a Java SDK, and some browser add-ons for testing. I don't know if the add-ons for testing work on AIX, but everything else should. The developer tools are otherwise supported on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried to download AIX version of GWT but I didn't get it from anywhere where as I found the Windows, Linux, Mac version of GWT. Thats why I suspect is AIX really supports GWT. If you say it supports, can you please provide me any document like GWT on AIX. I didn't find any document related to that.

Comment: You only need the Plugin and SDK, located here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html

Comment: The plugin is for Eclipse, which is a Java-based application.

Comment: We have an front-end application which uses GWT. The application currently running on Solaris. 
Now we want to migrate that application from Solaris to AIX. As we know our application can migrate to AIX but one thing we are worried about is if GWT can be able migrate to AIX or not.
If GWT can be migrate, can you guide us how we can achieve that.