# Can google web toolkit(GWT ) migrate to AIX?

Tags: gwt, aix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can google web toolkit(GWT ) used on AIX ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592469/can-google-web-toolkitgwt-used-on-aix)

Currently GWT works on Solaris... is it possible to migrate it to AIX. If so is there any online document available on the net. Please provide for the same.

Comment: Are you referring to the dev environment or the applications, themselves?

Comment: I am referring to GWT application.

Answer (score 0):

GWT application not runs on Windows, Linux, Solaris, AIX etc. It runs on application server like Tomcat, JBoss, Websphere. Generally speaking you need just install application .war file on the other machine.
However - there is also one more question to consider - is your application using some server specific API's